# "object Promise" instead of value node.js

Tags: node.js

```
async function lol(func_group){
        let ok = await roblox.getUsernameFromId(func_group);
        console.log(func_group)
        console.log(role)
        return ok;
}
```

This returns the correct values in the console, but when the function is called on, it shows [object Promise]
Any solutions?

Comment: provide additional details

Answer (score 0):

Any async function will return a `Promise`, so the correct way to call it is:

```
const result = await lol(args)
```

**Solution:** Add this missing `await`.